という意味で what does it mean?

女子:　警子ちゃん、これから寝るまでって何してるんだ？
警子:　別に何も……明日の予習くらいか
女子:　だよなぁ……
警子:　分かっている。私達にはそれしかないのだ。
女子:　だけれども、ここに１年長くいるという意味では先輩の警子から、何かしらヒントが欲しかったのもまた事実で。

So the protagonist asks 警子 what she does in her free time and she tells her this. But what does という意味では here mean?
For context, the character is a young girl who just moved to this new private school. So she's trying to gather what people do in their free time from 警子 who has been here a longer time.
I understand "先輩の警子から、何かしらヒントが欲しかったのもまた事実で。" "It's true I want some kind of hint from here (about her life I suppose?)"

意味 means one of 内容, 意図, 理由, 目的, 気持ち, or 考え. Choose one. I personally think it is 目的.

～という意味で means "in the sense of/that ～". "そういう意味で" means "in this sense". "熱いという意味ではなく辛いという意味のホット" means "hot, not in the sense of temperature but in the sense of spicy".

～という意味で
in the sense of ～
ここに１年長くいるという意味で
in the sense of having been here a year longer
ここに１年長くいるという意味で先輩だ。
[She] is, in the sense of having been here a year longer, my senior.
ここに１年長くいるという意味で先輩の警子
Keiko, who is, in the sense of having been here a year longer, my senior
ここに１年長くいるという意味では先輩の警子
Keiko, who is, at least in the sense of having been here a year longer, my senior

This は is a contrastive-wa. It implies this girl does not usually regard Keiko as her sempai. The "hint" is not about someone's life but about how to pass the time before sleeping.
